# Regex to validate objectid of parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

Is there a regex or rules that can be use to validate whether a string is a valid objectid of an object in parse.com? 
We have a specific use case where an user has to copy a objectid from parse.com and insert into a webpage. We want to ensure the user has entered a correct objectid.

Comment: I think it would be wise to add the conditions for an objectid here, because not everyone knows what a parse.com objectid should look like.

Comment: Hi David, if i knew all conditions for the objectid, i would have devised all rules myself and not post this question :-). All I know from observation for now that it is an alphanumeric string with length 8. But if someone can confirm this then i can get the regex myself